# Evans conjecture for symmetric latin squares

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, latin-square

The Evans conjecture ( which was proved later by Smetaniuk) states that for any $n$, if at most $n-1$ entries of a partial $n\times n$ latin square are filled,  it can be completed to the full latin square.

My question pertains to whether this is applicable to symmetric (or commutative) latin square? That is, given $n\times n$ latin square, with at most $n-1$ prefilled entries ( which are symmetric with respect to diagonal), can it be completed to a symmetric latin square? Note that this corresponds to pre- total coloring of a complete graph of order $n$ with at most $n-1$ previous filled colors.  Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, when it comes to symmetric latin squares it is no longer true that as many as $n-1$ cells can be prescribed unconditionally. This is explained in the Ph.D. thesis of [Matthew Henderson.](https://mjh-phd.netlify.app/sec110.html)

> The key point here is that in a symmetric latin square, precisely
> because of the symmetry, every symbol $\sigma$ occurs an even number
> of times in cells outside of the main diagonal. Therefore, as every
> symbol $\sigma$ occurs $n$  times in total it follows that the number
> of cells of the main diagonal containing symbol $\sigma$ is congruent
> to $n$ modulo 2. A partial latin square can be incompletable because
> there are more symbols which occur on the main diagonal a number of
> times (zero included) incongruent to $n$  modulo 2 than there are
> empty cells on the main diagonal.
> If this obstruction does not occur the diagonal is called "admissible". For $n$ odd a diagonal is admissible if and only if no symbol occurs more than once on it.

The generalization of Evans theorem to symmetric latin squares by [Andersen and Hilton](https://www.academia.edu/20306267/Symmetric_latin_square_and_complete_graph_analogues_of_the_evans_conjecture) is that the symmetric latin square is completable if the diagonal is admissible and at most $n-1$ cells in total are prescribed.

In response to the comment by Richard Stanley: it is not sufficient to only count cells on or above the main diagonal, as this counter example shows. The diagonal is admissible ($n=5$ is odd and no symbol appears more than once on the diagonal), and the number of prescribed cells on or above the main diagonal is $n-1=4$, and yet the latin square is not completable.

[image]

Comment: Is this the only obstruction to completing a partial symmetric latin square with $n-1$ symbols? This might be the correct analogue of Evans conjecture for symmetric latin squares. Even more strongly, is it possible that you can specify $n-1$ symbols on or above the main diagonal, as long as you satisfy: (1) when you reflect the symbols about the main diagonal, we have a partial latin square, and (2) Carlo's condition?

Comment: The problem mentions "Evans conjecture", this answer mentions "Evans theorem". Please, @RichardStanley or anyone else, clarify for me the relation (if any) between the two.

Comment: @GerryMyerson --- the completability condition for nonsymmetric Latin squares was conjectured by Evans in 1960 and proven by Smetaniuk in 1981.

Comment: OK, so, there isn't an Evans theorem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the common practice is here, if a conjecture is proven can we then change its name into a theorem? Fermat's last theorem was called a conjecture in older books, but I guess it would be strange to keep calling it a conjecture now. There could be a confusion with other theorems of Evans, but the only one I found was the Evans-Krylov theorem.

Comment: Surely it makes more sense to call it Smetaniuk's Theorem?